# How can I construct my objects allocated through std::allocator::allocate()?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, allocator

C++20 removed the `construct()` and `destruct()` members from `std::allocator`. How am I supposed to construct my objects allocated through `std::allocator<T>::allocate()`? I found `std::uninitialized_fill()` and `std::uninitialized_copy()`, but as far as I understood they are not allocator-aware, and they do copies, which I think would hurt performance a lot for non-POD types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `std::allocator_traits`.

The point of removing the construct method is because the allocator traits already has that method, and the STL containers use `std::allocator_traits::construct` anyway.

[Documentation in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct)

And here is a little example: (`Alloc` is any allocator)

```
Alloc a{};
std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer i = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate(a, allocated_size);

// You use the construct and destroy methods from the allocator traits
std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(a, i, value_to_construt);
std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(a, i);

std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(a, i, allocated_size);
```

Comment: `Alloc::pointer` is also removed in C++20. Just use the trait throughout, or better yet `auto`: `extern Alloc a; using AT = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>; auto p = AT::allocate(a, count); AT::construct(a, p + i, constructor_arguments); AT::destroy(a, p + i); AT::deallocate(a, p, count);`

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks. I forgot that `::pointer` was removed too.

Comment: Also, I believe you're supposed to pass `std::to_address(i)` to `construct`, not `i`. `construct` takes a pointer; `i` is whatever the allocator wants it to be.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. How am I supposed to construct multiple elements at once?
Currently, Im reimplementing a vector container. I am using this static construct member function to construct 5 elements to their default value, after the user passed the vector's size.

Comment: If you want to construct multimple elements, you will have to iterate. This is how [I did it](https://github.com/Polo123456789/contenedoresSTL/blob/main/include/psg/vector/constructors.hpp#L22). Just look at the construction, and ignore the clean up in case the defautl construction throws, I currently in the reworks for that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a `static` form of `construct` still exists in C++20. Maybe that is intended to replace the original form of `construct`?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct

I have not really done much with custom allocation so I don't have personal experience using these functions, but it seems reasonable that they might prefer a static function in an effort to break dependencies.

There is also a `construct_at` function that is added with C++20.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at

Comment: `allocator_traits::construct` is the correct (also backwards-compatible) answer. When writing any code consuming standard allocators, its almost always expected that functionality is used via `allocator_traits` rather than the allocator type itself -- which allows for allocators to effectively be given statically defined "default" implementations of some functions (such as `construct`, etc). Technically C++20 onward, `construct_at` and `allocator_traits::construct` would be synonymous though

Comment: @Human-Compiler Equivalence for `std::allocator` is not that interesting in the context of using allocators. Not every allocator is `std::allocator`.

Comment: @deduplicator You appear to misunderstand; I am referring to the standard allocator *concept*, not `std::allocator`. The expected way to interact with any allocator generically is  to use `allocator_traits` because certain functions or features need not be explicitly defined, and `allocator_traits` provides these defaults.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I was referring to your last sentence. [`std::construct_at`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) is only equivalent to [`std::allocator_traits::construct()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) for [`std::allocator`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah I see what you are getting at -- fair enough